# How to add an action to the button in Controller of magento?

Tags: php, magento

```
 $fieldset->addField('test_connection', 'submit', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('rpos_connect')->__('Test Connection'),
            'required'  => true,
            'value'  => 'Test',
            'after_element_html' => '',
            'tabindex' => 1

        ));
```

This is my PHP code to prepare a form with a button in my module block folder.Now I want this to call a function named `testAction()` in my Controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onclick as follows.

```
'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/controller/action')}')"
```

Comment: Thank you..... for the help but There is one more change to be done i.e.,  change `submit` to `button`.